# Jenkins - sometimes (non-deteministic?) mark builds as failed, because of batch command

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I execute following batch ('Execute Windows batch command') through Jenkins. Although it always (tested more than 50 times) works when I build my project 'manually' (when I click on 'build' button), it sometimes crashes during  scheduled builds.

```
REM
REM get date in following format - day name - day - month name - year
REM

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do (set dt=%%a)

set year=%dt:~0,4%
set month=%dt:~4,2%
set day=%dt:~6,2%

if %month%==01 set month=Jan
if %month%==02 set month=Feb
if %month%==03 set month=Mar
if %month%==04 set month=Apr
if %month%==05 set month=May
if %month%==06 set month=Jun
if %month%==07 set month=Jul
if %month%==08 set month=Aug
if %month%==09 set month=Sep
if %month%==10 set month=Oct
if %month%==11 set month=Nov
if %month%==12 set month=Dec

For /f %%# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek^|Findstr [1-7]') Do (Set DOW=%%#)

if %dow%==1 set dow=Monday
if %dow%==2 set dow=Tuesday
if %dow%==3 set dow=Wednesday
if %dow%==4 set dow=Thursday
if %dow%==5 set dow=Friday
if %dow%==6 set dow=Saturday
if %dow%==7 set dow=Sunday

set dayinfo=%dow% - %day%-%month%-%year%
```

The error message is as follows:

> For> /F
>   %# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek|Findstr [1-7]') Do
>   (Set DOW=%# ) set was unexpected at this time.
>   if> ==1
>   set dow=Monday Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build
>   as failure

Since I am unable to reproduce it - is it possible to make batch command not mark build as failed?
Is it a bug in Jenkins or within my batch file?

Comment: I've got similar problems when I called some scripts. The solution was to launch with 'call' like `call my_script.exe`

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to make batch command not mark build as failed?

Yes, write `echo Done` or something as the last line in your **Execute Windows Batch Command** step (not in the batch itself). Since that line will always succeed, the whole step will be marked as successful always. Obviously, you are foregoing any possibility of the script failing for valid reasons though.

Now, the reason your script is failing is because in some circumstances (undetermined), your value for `DOW` is not set. So the comparison statement becomes invalid as it has no left side.

To avoid this, you should always quote your variables and strings in comparison.
`if "%dow%"=="1" set dow=Monday`
`if "%dow%"=="2" set dow=Tuesday`

This way, at least the script won't fail due to syntax errors, however you will still end up with empty `dow` (and incomplete `dayinfo`)

To figure out why exactly your `dow` ends up being empty sometimes, you need to actually see the result of the command that generates it's value. So do the following:

`WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek`
`For /f %%# In ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get DayOfWeek^|Findstr [1-7]') Do (Set DOW=%%#)`

When it's successful, it will display the full output of the command in console. When it fails, you will see the error of that command, and take it from there.